# VBA code to copy & paste based on a term and a Date range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that has thousands of rows (Template) and I've created a code to filter based on key terms, so that, only active projects are copied to a new worksheet (Report). However, now, I would like it to also show any projects completed in the last 2 weeks.

I am pretty new to VBA so I am not sure how to add a step that would look at column D and determine whether it falls within a date range that is between "today" and "today - 14 days"

This is the code I am using:

```
Sub Copy_Data()

    Dim Src As Worksheet, Dst As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, r As Range
    Dim CopyRange As Range

    Set Src = Sheets("Template")
    Set Dst = Sheets("Report")

    LastRow = Src.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").Row
    For Each r In Src.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
        If r.Value = "Planning" Or r.Value = "On Hold" Or r.Value = "Acknowledged" Or r.Value = "Gathering Info" Or r.Value = "" Then
            If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                Set CopyRange = r.EntireRow
            Else
                Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, r.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
        CopyRange.Copy Dst.Range("A3")
    End If

End Sub
```

I did try using the record macro, but my knowledge of proper syntax is limited.

Comment: This question can't be answered without an example of data in column D, and preferably a general example of (mock-up) data to run/test a solution on.

Comment: Have a look at `datediff`. Looks like you're up to it!

Comment: you simply check whether the given *date value* is >= 14 days ago and <= today. You can use the `DateAdd("d",-14, Date)` function to get that lower bound (14 days ago). Which also hints that `Date` will return today's date. Try it?

Comment: @DavidZemens Where would I add that line?

Comment: Why don't you try a few things and see if you can figure it out?

Comment: @DavidZemens I tried a few places, but I think the issue I am having is that I need it to look at column c first to see if it is marked as "Completed", an for the other terms like "On Hold" it doesn't need to reference the date.

Comment: well, your `For` loop is iterating column B, and `r` is each cell in that column, so `r.Offset(0,1)` is the cell in column C, and `r.offset(0,2)` would be column D. You just need to use some nested `If` statement(s).

Comment: @DavidZemens Thank you I will try that.